# morphia nested document query

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a nested document like this -

```
"name" : "Naman",
"gender" : "M",
"occupation" : {
    "company" : "Honda",
    "designation" : "manager",
    "salary" : "1000000",
}
```

How do I write a query in morphia that gives me all those people with company, say : "Honda" and post "manager"

Comment: Can you show us your attempt with morphia code ?

Comment: I found the solution ... query.and(
            query.criteria("occupation.designation").equal("manager"),
            query.criteria("occupation.company").equal("Honda")
        );

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
db.yourcollection.find({'occupation.company':'Honda','occupation.designation':'manager'})
```

use [Dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) of mongoDB to get values from nested array/document